# set up remote SVN ref for existing git repository

Tags: git, svn

We are following this link (http://kris.me.uk/2010/10/01/svn-master-with-git-mirrors.html) and it is working well.

Now we are hosting the remote git repository in gitlab.

The basic work flow is

SVN MASTER -> git fetcher -> git mirror | > local git

Cloning the git mirror works fine but when I try and set up the SVN remote locally to point back to the original SVN MASTER I get the following error:

"Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history"

I am using the following SVN init command AFTER cloning the git mirror.

*git svn init --prefix=root/ -s svn://path/*

The clone does have the proper git-svn meta information on the commits.

How do I set up the svn remote on an existing cloned repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the mirror was set up with the IP address and I was trying to do the svn init with the name.

Make sure your git-svn-id server path correctly matches.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "consuming" after typing git help svn. You'll see the answer right there.

Comment: I don't want all future pulls to come from the master svn server. They will still pull from the git mirror. I just need the ability to dcommit from the local copy of the git mirror to the svn master.